# Error NetTrain::invencin: Invalid input when training a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I've build a Deep neural network with various variables:

```
 net = NetGraph[
        {CatenateLayer[], 200, DropoutLayer[], Ramp, 100, DropoutLayer[], Ramp, 100, 
         BatchNormalizationLayer[], LogisticSigmoid, 50, DropoutLayer[],  Ramp, 2,  SoftmaxLayer[]}, 
        {{NetPort["A"], NetPort["B"], NetPort["C"], NetPort["D"], NetPort["E"], NetPort["F"], 
          NetPort["G"], NetPort["H"], NetPort["I"], NetPort["J"], NetPort["Input"]} -> 
           1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> 11 -> 12 -> 13 -> 14 -> 15 -> 
            NetPort["Output"]},
        "A" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", GetLevels[1], "UnitVector"}], 
        "B" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", GetLevels[2], "UnitVector"}],
        "C" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", {1, 2, 3, 4}, "UnitVector"}],
        "D" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", GetLevels[4], "UnitVector"}],
        "E" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", pays, "UnitVector"}],
        "F" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", pays, "UnitVector"}],
        "G" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", pays, "UnitVector"}],
        "H" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", GetLevels[8], "UnitVector"}],
        "I" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", GetLevels[9], "UnitVector"}],
        "J" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", GetLevels[10], "UnitVector"}],
        "Input" -> 5,
        "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {"NO", "Yes"}}]
      ]
```

The net initialize with no issue.

I create a Association

```
  <|"A" -> "0010", "B" -> "1025", "C" -> 4.`, "D" -> "091502", "E" -> "532", "F" -> "532", 
    "G" -> "532", "H" -> "48", "I" -> "FOB", "J" -> "0199999374", 
    "Input" -> {0.`, 0.09`, 0.5073096782088804`, 0.04`, 1.`}, 
    "Output" -> "oui"|>
```

I even created `DataSet` from my training set, but still I'm getting the following
error:

> NetTrain::invencin: Invalid input, <<1291>>.

By the way, I tried this same architecture on a subset of the data, and the training went smoothly.

Comment: Please add your `NetTrain` invocation to your question, since that is what is erroring.

Comment: I just restarted the machine and everything is going well.  I think I must have had not enough memory left.

Answer (score 2):

The error has to do with not enough memory left to train the model